# How to cut object in directx 9

Tags: c++, scroll, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to make a scrollbar in my DirectX 9 application, but I don't know how to cut objects when they are hitting end of the panel where elements with scroll bar placed at. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to cut objects going outside of some rectangular area with scrollbar. In this case you can enable [Scissor Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147354(v=vs.85).aspx).